# NoClassDefFoundError with Java Applet

Tags: java, applet, noclassdeffounderror

I have created a Java Applet that make use of another Java class that I have also created. The Java class create a Telnet session to a remote device (making use of the package org.apache.commons) and the Applet invoke methods of this class. The answer to any Telnet command is received as a String that the Applet should print in a Web page. This is the Applet's code:

```
package m2mcom.web;
import m2mcom.entities.AutomatedTelnetClient;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Displaytext extends Applet {
    String text;
    public void init() {
        AutomatedTelnetClient telnet = new AutomatedTelnetClient("192.168.1.1");
        String text = telnet.sendCommand("display device");
        telnet.disconnect();
    }   
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString(text,40,20);
    }
}
```

And when I execute the .html file I get this error message:

```
NoClassDefFoundError. DisplayText(wrong name: m2mcom/web/DisplayText)
```

In conclusion, I don't know if I am not arranging properly the files directory, or simply it is not possible to invoke other methods class from an Applet this way. Anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong?

### HTML

This HTML was copied from a comment and formatted.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div>
<APPLET
    CODE="Displaytext.class"
    WIDTH="800"
    HEIGHT="500">
</APPLET>
</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: If you copy pasted... Error message is looking for `DisplayText` class but the class you defined is `Displaytext` class.

Comment: Some comments.  1) Don't type 'something like' the errors, code or HTML.  Copy/paste it, always!  2) Don't put code, code snippets, HTML or exception output in comments.  It is unreadable!    3) After copy/pasting that stuff as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14519443/edit), make sure it is nicely formatted like the code and HTML above, using the code formatting button above the message posting area `{}`. -- Note that applet and coding problems can be quite tricky to solve.  Unless you can mange to provide accurate information we have *no hope* of helping you sort it.

Answer (score 1):

Take the class name last parts of:

```
NoClassDefFoundError. DisplayText(wrong name: m2mcom/web/DisplayText)
```

&

```
public class Displaytext extends Applet {
```

And we end up with these two (non-equivalent) strings:

```
DisplayText
Displaytext
```

Notice the difference?

### Tips

1. `AutomatedTelnetClient("192.168.1.1")` Implies to me that this applet will attempt to reach cross-site.  To do so it will need to be digitally signed and trusted.
2. Don't code using AWT components in this millennium.  Replace `Applet` with `JApplet`.
3. Don't override `paint(Graphics)` just in order to draw a `String`!  Add it to a text component and add the component to the applet.
4. But if it actually needs custom painting, don't do it in a top level container.

Comment: I don't understand that comment.